# How can I tell if my Titanium app is running on the simulator or not?

Tags: titanium

I need to mock test data instead of trying to use the camera while debugging with the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the value of `Titanium.Platform.model` for this. IIRC, it returns `x86_64` on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks - at the moment I am getting Titanium.Platform.model = "Simulator"

Comment: Sweet, they must have tweaked that.