# Is it possible to tell if it runs on simulator or real device in the application

Tags: android, ios, xcode, titanium

I would like to change some parameters when it is works in simulator or 
on server.

for example => server name

- On simulator => localhost
- On real device => myserver.com

For now, my environment is titanium.

However I would like to know it is possible on Xcode.

It could be a good hint for me and If imopposible onxcode, it is impossible in titanium either.

Comment: For XCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775420/programmatically-detect-if-app-is-being-run-on-device-or-simulator or for Titanium http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090844/how-can-i-tell-if-my-titanium-app-is-running-on-the-simulator-or-not ?

Comment: Thank you this link works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Android

```
Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
```

For iOS

```
#define SIM(x) if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice].model lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"simulator"].location != NSNotFound){x;}

SIM(NSLog(@"This will only be logged if the device is simulated"));
```